# Can IntelliJ make spelling suggestions?

Tags: intellij-idea

IntelliJ tells me that I write words wrongly. That is cool. However, it does not give me any suggestions how to write them correctly, making this feature only half as useful as it could be. Can I get IntelliJ to make spelling suggestions? Working on KDE, many of my usual programs use the KDE spelling and thus are able to make suggestions...

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the misspelled word -> Spelling -> Typo: Change to...

[image]

Comment: Nope. That just gives me "Typo: Rename to..." (which does not bring me to suggestions, but just re-factoring) and the option to save the word to the dictionary.

Comment: Nice, but I don't get this :-(

Comment: Try to see if you have some dictonary registered in Preferences -> Editor -> Spelling -> Dictionaries

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: I don't have any more hint :(

Answer (score 1):

Right click or press 
<kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
on the misspelled word. It will display a menu like this -
[image: Spell check menu]

On the first option, you have a sub menu which you can expand on the right but to access the spell check options, you need to select the option itself that is highlight in the screenshot above, and it will replace the context menu with another one, listing the possible spelling suggestions -
[image]

I too struggled finding this option. The menu option available (first screenshot) looks like "can be expanded only" and is not at all selectable, visibly.